# How to crop face section from an image with given corner points. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to crop a face section from an image but face image is not straight/vertically aligned. I am having four pixel points to crop it..
Problem is that, 
If i will transform image first the pixel points cannot be used thereafter to crop the facial section out of it.
Or in other case I am not having an exact bounding box to crop the image directly using imcrop as facial sections  are somewhat tilted left or right.
The four pixel points are at forehead , chin and ears of the face to be cropped.

Comment: Can you add the image, possibly to any image hosting site and post a link? also with expected results would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [poly2mask](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html). This function produces a mask image from your given x and y coordinates:

```
BW = poly2mask(x,y,m,n);
```

where `x` and `y` are your coordinates, and the produced `BW` image is `m` by `n`. You can then use this `BW` image to mask your original image `I` by doing

```
I(~BW) = 0;
```

If you actually want to crop, then you could get the bounding box (either through the [regionprops](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function or the code below):

```
x1 =  round(min(x));
y1 =  round(min(y));
x2 =  round(max(x));
y2 =  round(max(y));
```

and then crop the image after you have used the `BW` as a mask.

```
I2 = I(x1:x2,y1:y2);
```

Hope that helps.